# OSX: Linker error for boost/filesystem with Xcode 8 and C++ 11

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, boost, linker-errors

This is my first question on SO. Here goes:

I'm trying to use the boost library - specifically the filesystem part - in a C++ project in Xcode 8.

### The problem:

`Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group`
`"boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)", referenced 
from:`

`"boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:`

`"boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_increment(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:`

`"boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:`

`"boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:`

`"boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:`

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

### The code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
std::string dir_path = "foo/bar";

if ( !boost::filesystem::exists( dir_path ) ) return false;

boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_itr; // default construction 
yields past-the-end
for ( boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr( dir_path );
itr != end_itr;
++itr )
{
std::cout << itr->path();
}

return 0;
```

}

### What I've done:

1. `brew install boost --build-from-source --c++11`. I read somewhere that passing this `--c++11` flag should fix it, and the `--build-from-source` is required so that the flag is actually passed to the b2 compiler.
2. `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` in my project.
3. Added `/usr/local/include` to my **Header Search Paths** under **Build Settings**. (Also tried adding `/usr/local/include/boost` and `/usr/local/include/boost/system` there, to no avail. Also, setting the **recursive** option on any of my Header Search Paths makes Xcode freak out).
4. Added `/usr/local/lib` to my **Library Search Paths**.
5. Added `-lboost_system -lboost_filesystem` to my **Other Linker Flags**. (Also tried adding `-lboost_system-mt`, which I saw other answers suggesting).
6. Tried to do what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28792589/6307454) says, but I have no **Link Libraries to Binary** section in my **Build Phases** section. Just **Target Dependencies** and **Compile Sources**.
7. By the way, restarting Xcode and/or my laptop didn't work. I read somewhere that someone could get it to work by reinstalling Xcode **after** having installed boost, but umm.. idk.

### Additional information

- Just trying to `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` causes the last 2 linker errors (about the `boost::system::system_category()` and `generic_category()`) to occur. However, with `#include <boost/regex.hpp>`, the program will build successfully.
- I also successfully installed boost following the steps 
  [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install) and were able run the programs from the boost/filesystem tutorial.
- I took into consideration passing the files I need to work with as `argvs[]` to my program, but I could be dealing with tens of thousands of files per folder and I suspect that might get ugly.
- OS version: 10.12.4
- Xcode version: 8.3.2

I am very new to C++ and almost as new to Xcode. I've spent about 8h trying to get this to work.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: C++11 questions should also use the normal C++ tag. For you, this will also increase the list of potential helpful people.

Comment: By the way, I decided to try out passing the file list as arguments to the executable.

I used `ls foo/bar | my_exe.exe`, grabbed the input from `std:cin` and it seems to be working decently for extracting audio features (e.g., MFCCs and their deltas) from ~12000 audio files and writing those features to respective text files.

I think this question is still interesting, since I couldn't find a way to fix this (and all other similar questions are pretty old).

Comment: @Jonas I added it, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and this is how I fixed it.

```
Build Settings > Header Search Paths > (Add) /usr/local/include
Build Settings > Library Search Paths > (Add) /usr/local/lib
Build Settings > Other Linker Flags > (Add) -l boost_system -l boost_filesystem
```

I hope this helps someone.